# whatsapp in Lumia 535

Tags: whatsapp

I face a difficulty in whatsapp in my lumia 535. That I can't forward any media(photo,video or audio) file to broadcast list which I made from my selected contacts.
Also the biggest problem is that I can't find any audio file in my phone which I already downloaded via whatsapp. So please give your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: For the unable to find audio file side of things, this has [already been answered here](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/411/106)

Answer (score 1):

Actually such audio and video files are saved on phone but there is no direct way to access them. However you can use a file manager app to list them out. I am using Lumia 535 (WP-8.1,RM-1090) and I can access all my audio/video files via a file manager app namely [Metro File Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/store/p/metro-file-manager/9wzdncrfhzqz). I can access all the media which I have downloaded from Whatsapp via path Phone\Pictures\WhatsApp. It is worth to note that although the folder is located in Pictures, it will hold all types of media shared via WhatsApp. I have already answered this [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/411/media-transferred-via-whatsapp).