# WhatsApp audio message file location

Tags: whatsapp, audio, nokia-lumia-525

I have a Nokia Lumia 525 running Windows Phone 8.1. I want to access an audio clip received through WhatsApp. How can I access the file to copy it to another location?

Comment: Possible duplciate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/411/media-transferred-via-whatsapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible at this time [per the information on the WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/30034176).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is possible to receive/send audio clips on Whatsapp. If the audio clip is an uploaded file (such as mp3 song) then it will be saved in ***SDcard/Phone -> Pictures -> Whatsapp***. You can also find it in Music player. The name of the file usually starts with "*AUD*" followed by date and time.

Any recordings made from the Whatsapp will be saved in ***SDcard/Phone -> Pictures -> Whatsapp -> PTT***

However the saved file will be in .ptt format which WP8.1 does not play by default.

[image: File location of Whatsapp recorded audio]

My current version of Whatsapp is v2.12.300.0. This feature is available for quite some time.

Answer (score -1):

Now you can have images and videos received from WhatsApp
 - Phone/SD Card -> Pictures -> WhatsApp

- And for audio files received using WhatsApp you will have that audio clips in "Music App" named like "AUD*".

Comment: Is this with a specific version of the WhatsApp client? Does a setting need to be set for this to work?

Comment: I didn't set anything for this to work, and this works with my WhatsApp, also when it gets updated.

Comment: It was neither attaching audio nor saving the audio received in internal or external memory but WhatsApp memory itself. Audio files with WhatsApp was automatically got working when it got updated(it was about 6 months ago), I didn't do anything.